What's going on in the top-left corner of this inserter factory?
I found this layout online for a mini-factory to produce every type of inserter, but for the life of me, I can't figure out what's going on in the top left corner.  The best I can tell, it just passes the gears through completely untouched using some underground belt shenanigans.  It this just a remnant that the original creator forgot to clean up, or does it actually serve some purpose?

Here is where I found the layout https://factorioprints.com/view/-K_Me61B1oQ_Dmjbde9B

The upper-left corner has a lane balancer:

Its purpose is to distribute all of the input items equally to both
sides of the output belt.  (In the context of the larger design, it
seems to not be needed, since all the gears get shoved onto the right
lane of column 3 anyway, but that's a separate issue.)
Note that the circuits shown on the belts in the above image never
move, since side-loaded undergrounds only draw from one side.  (And of
course it does not matter what specific items are on the belt.)
Why use this lane balancer instead of just one splitter and a
side-loaded merge?  It turns out the 1-splitter design does not draw
evenly from both sides under some circumstances.  The following image
illustrates the problem with the 1-splitter design, and compares to the
2-splitter, 3-underground design:

In both cases, items are being removed only from the right side of the
output belt.  For the 1-splitter design, only the red circuits get
consumed because they take priority due to being side-loaded first.
For the 2-splitter design, red and green are mixed evenly because
the undergrounds ensure that only the right lane of the final splitter
gets used, and hence there is no side-loading priority issue.
(The image suggests there is something wrong with the left side output
of the 2-splitter case, since it only contains green circuits, but
that's an artifact of how the belts fill initially in this setup.
Adding a consumer will get them mixing.)
Alternative image for red-green colorblindness, substituting red explosives for red circuits.

Whoo boy, this game is not accessible to those with red-green colorblindness. I don’t usually have too much trouble, but I cannot tell what you’re pointing out on the top of this. The bottom is clearer (because those are solid lines of color, I guess?), but I don’t know what the four lines on the top are.

@KRyan I've made and linked to an alternate version that uses red explosives in place of the red circuits.  Since the graphics for the explosives are fairly different, that should hopefully be easier to read.

Cool, thanks for that! Surprised to see them—they both look “uneven” to me, just on opposite sides—but then I don’t play this game, so there may simply be context I don’t have.

@KRyan The "unevenness" on the left output lane of the 2-splitter, 3-underground design is just a temporary condition caused by how the belts fill when this setup is first turned on.  Nothing is currently consuming anything from that lane, so the initial condition does not settle away.  In contrast, the lack of mixing in the right output lane of the 1-splitter design is its steady state, as the inserter is removing things from that lane continuously (but slowly).  This is what the parenthetical paragraph toward the end is trying to say.

That is a lane balancer for the belt of gears. When sideloading onto an underground belt, only one lane is actually accepted (the graphics in that image are from an old version; this is clearer with newer graphics). In that section, after the first splitter, only the right lane of the top belt is sideloaded into the right lane of its underground, and the left lane of the bottom belt is sideloaded into the right lane of the underground. So, going into the second splitter, the two right lanes of each input belt correspond to the original right and left lanes of the original belt respectively, and then that splitter balances those two right lanes. The belts after those splitter merge the balanced right lanes into both lanes of a single belt.
